# Is this the best way to use local storage when uploading to the web?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

So I'm appending images in a for loop to the same page depending on the link that is being clicked on I have a logic.js file:

```
var liquidityImages = ["Images"
var structureImages = ["Images"];
var sndImages = ["images"]

// Function to change images
function changeImages(imagesArray) {
  // Save the selected images array to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('selectedImages', JSON.stringify(imagesArray));
  // Navigate to the replicable-page.html
  window.location.href = 'page1.html';
}
```

and the appending function

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Retrieve the selected images array from localStorage
    var selectedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedImages')) || [];
  
    // Call the changeImages function to append the images
    changeImages(selectedImages);
  });
  
  function changeImages(imagesArray) {
    // Clear existing images
    var imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');
    imageContainer.innerHTML = "";
  
    // Loop through the selected array and append images
    for (var i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
      var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
      imgElement.src = imagesArray[i];
      imgElement.alt = "Image " + (i + 1); // Provide an alt attribute for accessibility
      imageContainer.appendChild(imgElement);
    }
  }
```

The question is, when i upload it to the server is this the best way or should i consider doing it differently because local storage can be a load on the page.

I tired doing it without the local storage logic and it didnt work at all

Comment: You shouldn't store "images" in local storage, that's for small local data, but since the limit is usually 5Mb you will run into issues very quickly. Also, there is no code here relating to uploading to the server, and you do not need localstorage to do so as you can directly send any string you store in localstorage to a server for processing instead.

Comment: @somethinghere i. think i miss explained myself, it only saves the string for the name of the variable and then pulls it back when it executes the function.
The question is maybe theres a better way to do it without saving the string to the local storage and parsing it to the function directly?

Comment: Itis not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. You want each user's browser to remember something? You have two functions called the same. The one loaded last will overwrite the other. Please be more descriptive of the actual thing you want to achieve

Comment: Again, you will run into localstorage size issues quickly. It isn’t really a great dolution but if all you want to do is save it on one then load it on another page, sure, but wonder if you really have to, because localstorage just isn’t made for that purpose.